# Guidelines for Angular and Openlayers application

Tags: angular, service, architecture, openlayers

What is the most suitable approach to building an app using angular and Openlayers?
I need to handle the map interaction and show some graphs. Also, edit features.
I was thinking of having a map component, a toolbar component and manage all the map interaction through service and observables. This is indeed a naive approach, any better idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For my use case I determined the best approach is to have a shared object Map where I handle all that is related to Openlayers Map. I got a map-browser.component for the browser map who got the map object as an input so I can share the behavior of the map with other component.

So my architecture look like:

- shared

  - map.ts
  - map.service.ts (Maybe to share the map context)
- map-browser

  - map-browser.component.ts
- layer
- geolocation
- control
- ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was not sure that embedding a component inside another component was the best approach.